# Подключение js библиотеки ajax'ом со стороннего сайта

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

День добрый, прошу совета.
Есть два проекта: сайт 1 и сайт 2.
Для сайта 1 необходимо чтобы тянулась информация с сайта 2.

На сайте 1 размещаю скрипт:

```
<div id="getData"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://site2.ru/exp/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
TESTLib.init(["-t1ORieXb14", "getData"]);
</script>
```

Сам скрипт main.js выглядит вот так:

```
<script>
var TESTLib = TESTLib || (function(){
    var _args = {};
    return {
        init : function(Args) {
            _args = Args;
            var feedUrl='http://site2.ru/exp/dataInfo.php?callback=?';
            var dataToSend='key='+_args[0];
            var updateContent=_args[1];

             $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  url: feedUrl,
                  data:dataToSend,
                  dataType: 'jsonp',
                  jsonp: "callback",
                  success: function(data){
                    $('#'+updateContent).append(data.HTML);
                  },
                  error: function(data){}  
                });
        },
    };
}());
</script>
```

в dataInfo.php формируются нужные данные и подключаются дополнительные стили и библиотеки:

```
if($typeConnect!='https'){
$html_ans.='<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://site2.ru/exp/style.css?v=1.2.9">';
$html_ans.='<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">';
$html_ans.='<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>';
$html_ans.='<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://site2.ru/exp/addOptions.js?v=1.2.9"></script>';
}
```

в файле addOptions.js различные настройки, к примеру, бустраповский тултип:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
});
</script>
```

В итоге:

1. Данные на site1 - благополучно приходят которые нужны.
2. стили и оформление - то же нормально подключаются.
3. а вот tooltip работать не хочет...

Я уверен что какой-то нюанс пропускаю, но не могу понять какой.
Просьба подсказать.

Comment: Вроде бы для тултипов Бутстрапа инициализация вручную не нужна...

Comment: Проверьте, может, тултип инициализируете до того, как добавляете на страницу элементы. Если правильно понимаю, в вашей ajax функции success: function(data){$('#'+updateContent).append(data.HTML);} добавляете на страницу элементы, которым нужен тултип? Тогда здесь же и нужно выполнять инициализацию тултипа $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

Comment: @YozhEzhi не инициализации не работает

Comment: @Stargazer дополнительный файл со скриптами - собственно где выполняется инициализация тултипа переписал так $(document).on('mouseenter','.actions-tools',function(){
 $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
}) , где actions-tools блок с иконками над которыми нужны тултипы... и заработало. решение не очень нравится, потому что не ясно почему оно работает...